# Glitch when running homemade script CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have been dinking around with batch files, and decided to have a little bit of fun creating a command usable in the command line "Hack", which looks like it will make it look like something bad is happening, but nothing really is. Here is the source for that:

```
@echo off

ECHO Parsing Buffer Strings...
Delay 3000
ECHO Reading Args from FTP Protocol...
Delay 3000
ECHO Interpreting BAUD rate...
Delay 3000
ECHO Reading IBM Standards...
Delay 3000
ECHO Removing Multiplexer matrices...
Delay 3000
ECHO Compiling zip files...
Delay 3000
ECHO Complete. System OS bypassed.
PAUSE
```

Now, as you may have noticed, there is no built-in "Delay" command, so I made one myself, placing the newly made Batch file in System32 along with Hack.bat:

```
@echo off
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w %1 > nul
```

This takes in one parameter, the amount of delay (ms), and pings a non-existent computer. It tries once to ping it, waiting %1 ms before it gives up. Now, when I put it the command "Hack", it says "Parsing buffer strings", waits three seconds, then the script stops. Now, when I turned echo on to see what the problem was, it said "Parsing buffer strings\nDelay 3000", waited three seconds, then the script stopped. Why? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

where is your procedure definition and it's call ? you shoud have done someting like :

```
echo parsing ...
call :delay 3000
echo reading ...
call :delay 3000
exit

:delay
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w %1 > nul
```

Comment: They are both batch files, and they are both in System32, making them both operable for command use.

Comment: Because otherwise your primary script will exit see http://www.robvanderwoude.com/call.php

Comment: All right, that makes sense. Is there any way so that the script doesn't exit when its done?

Comment: Yep replace exit by pause or by nothing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32353/discussion-between-elias-benevedes-and-kayasax)

Answer (score 2):

`ping addr -n 1 -w 3000` will only work as long as `addr` is unreachable. When for some reason the address becomes reachable, the command will return immediately. It will also pollute the network (just a little, but still).

If you don't need millisecond delays, a better approach would be something like this:

```cmd
@echo off

echo %TIME%
call :delay 5
echo %TIME%
goto :eof

:delay
set /a count=%1+1
ping -n %count% 127.0.0.1 >nul
```

Output:

```
C:\>delay.cmd
12:47:44,33
12:47:49,38
```

`ping` has a delay of roughly 1 second between two echo requests, so you can sleep for *n* seconds by sending *n+1* echo requests to localhost.